# What is the technical name for this movement performed by Master Wong in Birth of the Dragon?

Tags: terminology, tai-chi, identification, shaolin

I recently watched Birth of the Dragon on Netflix, and absolutely loved it. However, one particular movement caught my eye above all others, simply for the overwhelming appearance that something unfortunate could happen to either party at any moment. The movement is performed by Master Wong during the final fight scene (timestamp included):

https://youtu.be/YdsXo_6BlUw?t=186

I understand that movies and TV can add interesting concepts to stunts for a "wow" factor, but I can't help but wonder if there's actual naming in the martial arts community for such a movement so that I can learn more about it.

---

What is the spinning movement performed by Master Wong called?

Comment: On other sites, the YouTube link becomes an embed; is that just a rep requirement issue that someone could fix with an edit, or should I include screenshots for future readers?

Comment: It's a per-site thing. I could have sworn there was a Meta topic requesting it, but I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That movement is essentially a mix of a [flying arm bar](https://jiujitsu-news.com/how-to-do-a-flying-armbar/) and a [spinning arm bar](https://howtheyplay.com/individual-sports/How-to-Do-a-Spinning-Armbar) with a bit of extra spinning added in to make it look more cinematic.

Comment: Note that these techniques are to submit the opponent. In a fight for your life, you would just break the arm, without worrying about controlling them to the ground.